# Suggestions how to get access to MINTO MILP solver?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, solver, branch-and-bound, history

I came across the MINTO MILP solver today. A solver i wasn't aware of or at least had not paid attention too. While development seem to have stopped two decades ago however i still wouldn't mind getting access to it. However the form [1](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/download.html) to request access seems to have bitrotten away. I know that the solver is still available on the NEOS servers and i have made attempts to contact MINTOs developers (including a Dr. Gu who works on a different popular Mixed-Integer solver today) and people at the CORAL institute which hosts the website [2](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/) of the solver.

#### Do you have any other ideas how to get access to this MILP solver?

#### Have you had any experience with this solver?

[1](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/download.html) [Download form](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/download.html)

[2](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/) [MINTO website](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/%7Eminto/)

Comment: Dr. Gu is the "Gu" of "Gurobi".
"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MINTO has not been updated in many years. It was innovative in its day, but most of its ideas like fractional cuts and presolve were incorporated years ago into commercial MILP solvers like CPLEX and Gurobi. For most applications today, the best option is one of the major commercial solvers like [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer) or [Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com); these are available at no-cost for academic users. For a MIP researcher who needs to modify the underlying branch-and-cut algorithms beyond what can be done with the commercial solvers, then the closest successor to MINTO is [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org).

Disclaimer: I was a graduate student at Georgia Tech when MINTO was developed; I worked at CPLEX previously and currently work for Gurobi.